gridded ()<-TRUE doesn't work in R 'sf' package
My old code is not working. I runned regression kriging on 2017 but now is working. Why?
I'm stuck this line
grid<- readShapePoints("D:/R.data/RSOC_WRB/01_data/00_tumdata/grid")
str(grid)
proj4string(grid)<- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=36 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
gridded(grid)<- TRUE
names(grid)
summary(grid)
spplot(grid, "silt", asp=1, col.regions=bpy.colors(64))

what can I do insted of this lines?
Especially  error is gridded ()<-TRUE
Help me please?
is there any alternatives lines for gridded()<_TRUE
